# Java netbeans: How to properly add libraries?

Tags: java, netbeans

currently I am getting this error when I try to run a project `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils`, there is no issue in compiling the code though.

My setup:

- OCRUtils (custom utility class), has some static methods which use several libraries, including org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.
- OCRChecker (program) references the OCRUtils project (technically it uses OCRUtils/dist/OCRUtils.jar I believe).
- I do not have the libraries on the OCRChecker project (This would solve the issue, but it is not a proper solution)

How do I make sure that the libraries are properly forwarded to OCRChecker?

I can also see that OCRUtils indeed has a `dist/lib` folder containing all the libraries, but it seems that project inclusion does not inclue them to my OCRChecker project.

Regards.

Comment: Are you using maven or not? With maven the solution would be easy. Maven is shipped with Netbeans for some time now and is a native project building tool for Netbeans.

Comment: Not using maven currently, but might be interesting to look into it

Comment: Have you tried editing OCRUtils manifest.mf file, so it contains a proper `Class-Path` entry that lists Apache String Utils? This should decouple your main project (OCRChecker) from having to specifiy the missing JAR in your project runtime classpath explicitly. Note that you should specify the classpath with final distribution directory layout in mind (it should also work when you move them jars).